# MS Dynamics AX 2009 - how to copy/install a self programmed extension?

Tags: installation, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

So, I've started with programming Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009, created a little own sample app in my dev-System, and now I want to install this on my test-system, which is running on some other comp.

My problem: I got no idea how to create an installer, or even how to install my AX extension by hand. No clue at all.

So, how would I install my self programmed AX extension by hand, and how create an installer for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the client buys a developer license your extension will be in the user layer - not at all ideal.

Alternatively you can build an environment for the client in another environment maybe at your office where you do have a developer license.  Make the changes in the layer you would want it in (suggest the CUS layer, if it's a customisation for that client).  All you do then is overwrite the client's axcus.aod file with the one from your environment.

This is easy to do where your changes are new objects, but where you make structure changes to standard Ax objects you might run into issues.
(Always make a copy of the client environment before doing this.)

Comment: Well, and how would one install when changes to the standard AX structure are made?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want to accomplish.  As I understand it you want to move your changes to another environment, correct?

Add all your objects to a project, export the project from  your dev environment and import into the other.

Make sure you have menu items and a link to them in your Main menu.

(Oh, I appologise if you misunderstood your question).

Comment: No, you understood my problem. How would I do this, if my customer has not bought a developer license, ie is not allowed to go into develop mode, has no license for the layer I used?

Answer (score 0):

The same way.  Since the changes on the std objects are made on the Cus layer, and will therefore be in the axcus.aod  file.

(The original std ax object will still exist in the sys/syp layer.)

For more on layers: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa851164.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I got no idea what "the same way" refers to. Your Answer seems to refer to something outside the answer??

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. You asked how you would install your changes.  The answer = is by overwriting the axcus.aod file with your changes.